# Regex for repeated number with symbols

Tags: regex

I have excluded possible false positives while detecting SSN. Ex:111111111, 222222222 etc., But i started getting falsepositives for the same false ssn's. they are 111-11-1111 and 222-22-2222 etc., As of now i am using regex \b111[ -]11[ -]1111\b to avoid false positives. Is there a way i can have a precise regex to detect repeated numbers with symbols? This will help me use a single regex in place a regex per decimal(0-9).

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
^([0-9])\1{2}[-]\1{2}[-]\1{4}$
```

Matches any number and \1 refers to the first capture group, i.e. the first number.

More in detail:

- matches the first number
- repeats that first match two times to have a block of 3 digits
- matches the dash
- repeats first number two times
- matches the dash
- repeats first number four times

Comment: This will also match: 1, 222222, 333333333333333, 4-4-4

Comment: This will match exactly 111-11-111, etc. : ^([0-9])\1{2}[-]\1{2}[-]\1{3}$

Comment: Close, that last {3} should be a {4}.  Also, I'd recommend you edit that new pattern into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a more efficient way, I haven't thought of it yet

```
(?=([0\-]|[1\-]|[2\-]|[3\-]|[4\-]|[5\-]|[6\-]|[7\-]|[8\-]|[9\-]|){11})\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}
```

- Instead of putting in the entirety of all 10 repeating patters, a slightly shorter method of using a lookahead can be used to make sure a pattern only has 11 characters, only containing a specific number and dashes.
- The ending pattern `\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}` will ensure the pattern is: (3 digits)-(2 digits)-(4 digits)